# How do I move the SmarterMail default domain store to a different drive?

Tags: email, email-server

[I've followed the instructions here](http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a1463/move-a-domain-to-a-different-hard-drive-on-the-same-server.aspx).

However, I'd like to move *all* of my domains onto a new drive. I can run a regex on this conf and get all of the Domains on a different drive, but I'd like to change the default Domain store point to that new drive for the future. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: * [I've mirrored this same question on the official forums](http://forums.smartertools.com/showthread.php/30235-How-do-I-move-the-SmarterMail-default-domain-store-to-a-different-drive?p=100510#post100510)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall and reinstall SmarterMail. When you install, you specify the domain storage path.

If this doesn't appeal to you, open up your mailconfig.xml at C:\Program Files\SmarterTools\SmarterMail\Service.

Find the following block of configuration directives:

```
<!-- ** Path Settings ******************************* -->
<spoolPath>c:\SmarterMail\Spool\</spoolPath>
<rootMailPath>c:\SmarterMail\</rootMailPath>
<imapRetrievalDownloadPath>c:\SmarterMail\ImapRetrieval\</imapRetrievalDownloadPath>
<archivePath>c:\SmarterMail\Archive\</archivePath>
<logPath>c:\SmarterMail\Logs\</logPath>
<popRetrievalDownloadPath>c:\SmarterMail\PopRetrieval</popRetrievalDownloadPath>
```

Set the rootMailPath to your heart's content. Don't forget to restart the service.

Comment: Seriously, that's the easiest way? You've got to be kidding?

Comment: Much better! =)

Comment: No problem, amigo